# Where can I find an English translation of the Hebrew "Sefer ben ha-melekh we-ha-nazir" or "Book of the Prince and the Ascetic" story?

Tags: translation

Here is an article about the story: https://journals.openedition.org/crm/13772#text

It was written by Abraham Ibn Hisday in the 13th century, roughly based on the Christian legend of Barlaam and Josaphat.

Comment: It was translated into German and Yiddish but I don't think it was translated into English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An English summary of the book is given in Meyer Waxman's [History of Jewish Literature, vol. 2](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uva.x002649947&view=1up&seq=11.) starting from p. 590.

The Hebrew version can be found [here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/43021.) and the German translation [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=J80OAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Prinz+und+Derwisch&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix84286bLrAhVqILkGHXtTBa4Q6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false).

There's also a Catalan translation of the story, [El príncep i el monjo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8486329213) with introduction and study by Tessa Calders i Artís (1987).